Firebase throws "Given sign-in provider is disabled for this project" error when I try to sign up user via app but able to add user via console
When I try to create a new user for my Android app using Email/Password sign-in provider, Firebase Authentication throws:

The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ Please verify the new email before changing email] " error

Even though Email/Password sign-in provider is enabled for the project.
However, if I create a new user for Email/Password sign-in provider via the Firebase console, this user is then able to login into the app using those credentials.
The app first lets the user use the app as an anonymous user, later when you create an account, the anonymous account is linked with the new credentials.
The code for linking accounts is as follows:
class AccountServiceImpl @Inject constructor(private val auth: FirebaseAuth){
    
    suspend fun linkAccount(email: String, password: String){
        val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password)
        auth.currentUser!!.linkWithCredential(credential).await()
  }

}

Stack trace for the error obtained via Firebase Crashlytics dashboard
Non-fatal Exception: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ Please verify the new email before changing email. ]
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzace.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:39)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadd.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:21)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzact.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:35)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacv.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:75)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:46)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyz.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:3)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzys.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:2)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:15)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:64)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:99)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:37)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:8)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:20)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadi.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:64)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:54)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:29)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyz.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:11)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:84)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzyj.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:134)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzacb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:110)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaas.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:17)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzadf.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:2)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
   at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0$com-google-firebase-concurrent-CustomThreadFactory(CustomThreadFactory.java:47)
   at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(:4)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)


This behavior change is due to the Email Enumeration protection feature that is enabled by default on new projects (created on or after Sep 15). There is an option to disable the feature, in case your app relies on this functionality.
On your Firebase dashboard go to:
Authentication > Settings > User Actions > Email enumeration protection
Disable Email enumeration protection.
For more details on the issue check out the GitHub issue here

Please note that if the option of disabling the Email Enumeration protection feature disappears in the future though, there is no alternative API.

In the error message, there is also specified that:

Please verify the new email before changing the email.

So before linking the user with credentials, verify the email first.

I'm not sure what the message means by "verify the new email". Does it mean that the email should be a working email id? The email I was using was a working Gmail ID

Try to use FirebaseUser#verifyBeforeUpdateEmail. Does it work now this way?

I replaced "auth.currentUser!!.linkWithCredential(credential).await()" with "auth.currentUser!!.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(email).await()" in my code. Now when trying to create an account it throws "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request"

I checked out the post, and there you mentioned to "either reauthenticate the user by asking for the credentials or you can sign the user out and let it authenticate again.". I'm not sure how to do either as the user is not registered with any credentials yet, as the session was anonymous.

Your operation should be performed in two steps. Verify the email address and then link with credentials. Have you tried to do this way?

I tried that but it did not work. Thanks for helping. I researched a bit more about the issue and found that the problem is actually with the Firebase auth settings. I will be posting the solution in answers.
